# API is not working in using RabbitMQ subsriber

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, webapi

I have created a job using Asp .net core, in which I am processing all the vendor invoices. I am setting all the invoices using one API called `InvoiceChangeStatusList` to fetch all the invoices. I am fetching around 500-1000 invoices to process. I am sending these invoices to `RabbitMQ` queue, which is then fetched by `RabbitMQ` subscriber.

I am deserializing data in subscriber and calling one API named `ProcessVendorInvoice`. `ProcessVendorInvoice` API is comprising multiple internal and external APIs.

When `ProcessVendorInvoice` API is called, I am getting this error:

```
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Xpo.Intermodal.Core.BaseApiClient.ApiClientBase.<GetAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
   at Stg.Intermodal.Gateway.Core.ApiClient.Clients.MasterData.ChargeApiClient.<GetAllChargeList>d__1.MoveNext()
   at Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application.QueryHandlers.InvoiceFindByPKQueryHandler.<GetVendorInvoiceDetails>d__20.MoveNext() in C:\VI\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\src\backend\Application\Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application\QueryHandlers\InvoiceFindByPKQueryHandler.cs:line 126
   at Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application.QueryHandlers.InvoiceFindByPKQueryHandler.<Handle>d__16.MoveNext() in C:\VI\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\src\backend\Application\Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application\QueryHandlers\InvoiceFindByPKQueryHandler.cs:line 70
   at Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application.Binders.VendorInvoiceBinder.VendorInvoiceFindByPK(Int32 vendorInvoiceId) in C:\VI\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\src\backend\Application\Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application\Binders\VendorInvoiceBinder.cs:line 146
   at Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application.Binders.ChangeVendorInvoiceStatusBinder.Find(Int32 vendorInvoiceId) in C:\VI\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\src\backend\Application\Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application\Binders\ChangeVendorInvoiceStatusBinder.cs:line 3293
   at Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application.Binders.ChangeVendorInvoiceStatusBinder.ChangeVendorInvoiceStatus(Int32 vendorInvoiceId, String userName, String status, Boolean manualApproved, Boolean isForcePost, Boolean IsCalculateAmount, VendorInvoicingSource processedBy) in C:\VI\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\src\backend\Application\Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application\Binders\ChangeVendorInvoiceStatusBinder.cs:line 109
   at Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application.Binders.ChangeVendorInvoiceStatusBinder.ProcessVendorInvoice(ChangeInvoiceStatus changeInvoiceStatus, String username) in C:\VI\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\src\backend\Application\Intermodal.VendorInvoice.Application\Binders\ChangeVendorInvoiceStatusBinder.cs:line 90
   at Intermodel.VendorInvoice.WebApi.Controllers.VendorInvoiceController.ProcessInvoice(ChangeInvoiceStatus invoiceStatus) in C:\VI\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\Intermodal-VendorInvoice\src\backend\Api\Intermodal.VendorInvoice.WebApi\Controllers\VendorInvoiceController.cs:line 160
```

I checked my code, there is not issue. When I run `ProcessVendorInvoice` using Postman, it works without giving error but when I run this API in loop this error is keep coming.

I don't know what I did wrong. Can you please tell me what the issue?

Comment: Investigate your serialized data, the `Int32 vendorInvoiceId` in particular. Looks like there are some deserialization issues and the API can't find invoice with this ID.